# Android Startup Services/Apps

Tags: android

what is the best way to list all services that start with the phone? Is there a SDK class, or should I check some system files manually?

Comment: This isn't really possible. Services don't actually start with the phone. What happens is broadcast receivers listen for the on_boot_complete broadcast and then may or may not start a service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Falmarri points out you should consider to look for all ***apps*** that deploy BroadcastReceivers listening to ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED action.

You might therefore hook up the following:

```
mPackageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = mPackageManager.queryBroadcastReceivers(new intent(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED), 0);
```

And since this might take a time, use handler and a thread or an AsyncTask to get the list (with maybe an additional app info and/or icon etc.).

And as for the list of running ***services***, you might check this code snippet [here](http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2010/02/01/showing-running-services-in-android/).

Have fun.